# Group by multiple columns ( one with comma separated and other with sum ) using Unix

Tags: unix

I have a text/csv file as follows:

```
EDMP_SCI|INACTIVE|12|AE

EDMP_SCI|INACTIVE|10|AO

EDMP_SCI|ACTIVE|20|IN

EDMP_SCI|ACTIVE|30|US

EDMP_EBBS|UNKNOWN|10|HK
```

I need to group by based on column1 and column2

(Column3 should have the sum of numbers and column4 should have comma separated values)

The required output should be like:

```
EDMP_SCI|INACTIVE|22|AE,AO

EDMP_SCI|ACTIVE|50|IN,US

EDMP_EBBS|UNKNOWN|10|HK
```

I am able to get sum and comma separated columns separately, but I need then to be done parallelly. I need this either by Unix shell script or any single command in Unix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`.

For example:

```
awk -F '|' '{print $1 "|" $2 " " $3" " $4}' input | awk '{sum[$1]+=$2}{loc[$1]=loc[$1]$3","}END{for(c in sum){print c"|"sum[c]"|"substr(loc[c],0,length(loc[c])-1)}}'
```

`input` is your data file.